# Center Horizontal Text

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using CardView for list my quote with author image. I am trying to set quote in center horizontal in list. I have tried center gravity and related method. But I am not success. My current view is showing like below

**Current**

[image]

**Need**

[image]

**My XML** is like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quoteActionView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/imageAuthorView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/textIndxQuote"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#444444"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textQuote"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Please check and let me know what I am missing.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last LinearLayout to this:

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: hi @babadaba ! its working fine :) Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `LinearLayout` height to `match_parent` and put `android:layout_gravity:"center"` or `android:layout_gravity:"center_vertical"` inside it.
Should work.